# What kind of changes did they make in Soul Calibur 5 that differed from Soul Calibur IV?

Tags: soul-calibur-5, soul-calibur-4

What kind of gameplay changes were made?

Comment: Please don't ask questions that solicit opinions; you know they're just going to get closed, man.

Comment: I think the question just falls within the bounds of legitimacy, thought the OP could narrow it to more specific aspects of the gameplay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite a few, in fact. Here are the first that come to my mind :

- **No more critical finish.** More or less replaced by Critical Edge, special moves that drain the Soul Gauge. Among which...
- **Guard impact is now a special**. Performed through 4A+B+K, it will consume half a level of Soul Gauge.
- **Character customization has been decoupled from the game mechanics** : Equipment no longer alters the character's stats. If you come across a guy in a silly costume, it's of his own will, not because he tried to max out Defense and HP.
- **Faster gameplay**. Versus time limit can no longer be disabled. The maximum time that can be set is 60 seconds. *Time Out* should be a rare occurence nevertheless as most move sets have been drastically sped up, with attacks being sensibly more powerful than before.
- **Movesets revisited**. Ivy's stances have been removed, Natsu, while a spiritual successor to Taki, plays differently... Everyone is faster, as I said before, and there's the addition of the Brave Edge moves.